# I'm unable to setup database on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, heroku, database-migration, rails-migrations

I'm trying to setup my Heroku app but when I'm trying to run `db:setup`, `db:create` then I get:

```
[hauleth@NIUNIOBOOK] Tori $ heroku run rake --trace db:setup
Running rake --trace db:setup attached to terminal... up, run.1
** Invoke db:setup (first_time)
** Invoke db:create (first_time)
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Invoke rails_env (first_time)
** Execute rails_env
rake aborted!
string not matched
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/tasks/misc.rake:4:in `[]='
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/tasks/misc.rake:4:in `block in <top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:176:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:157:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:176:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:157:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:176:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:157:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in top_level'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in `block in run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:setup => db:create => db:load_config => rails_env
```

And when I try `db:migrate` then:

```
[hauleth@NIUNIOBOOK] Tori $ heroku run rake --trace db:migrate
Running rake --trace db:migrate attached to terminal... up, run.1
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rake aborted!
Invalid DATABASE_URL
(erb):9:in `rescue in <main>'
(erb):6:in `<main>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/erb.rb:753:in `eval'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/erb.rb:753:in `result'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:106:in `database_configuration'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `instance_eval'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:26:in `on_load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:67:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/application.rb:96:in `initialize!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `block in require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:640:in `new_constants_in'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/application.rb:83:in `require_environment!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/application.rb:193:in `block (2 levels) in initialize_tasks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:176:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:157:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in top_level'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in `block in run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
```

How to fix that? I'm running on Cedar stack with Rails 3.1.3.

I have tested that Ruby see `ENV['DATABASE_URL']` and also I've tested that `URI.parse` works on it. So where is the exception?

**EDIT**
It's my first migration in new app. I'v checked that `heroku run console` can access the `ENV['DATABASE_URL']` and than `URI#parse` is not throwin' any error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed that by recreating full Git an Heroku app.

Answer (score 0):

Your `DATABASE_URL` might be missing or nil.

Check with:

```
heroku config
```

If it looks OK, try re-adding the add-on:

```
heroku addons:remove shared-database:5mb
heroku addons:add shared-database:5mb
```

Comment: Still at is be. I've checked thet it's present and also that is visible (in `heroku run console`). It's also correctly parsed by `URI#parse`.